# txt to datagridview error

Tags: c#, datagridview, io

I have a text file

```
No  TMNo    EnNo    Name        GMNo    Mode    IN/OUT  Antipass    DaiGong DateTime
1   1   00000001        1   1       1   0   2014-03-19  16:16:14
2   1   00000001        1   1       3   0   2014-03-19  16:16:20
3   1   00000001        1   1       3   0   2014-03-19  16:17:03
4   1   00000001        1   1       3   0   2014-03-19  16:17:17
```

and when i am lording it in datagridview it shows,

[image]

may be it because the there is no space between two tab (/t).

my code for it is..

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Nisar\workspace\biometric\backup data\AGL_001.TXT");
        if (lines.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var columnName in lines.FirstOrDefault()
                .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName);
            }
            foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(1))
            {
                var cellArray = cellValues
                    .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                //if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some char not visible is present between the EnNo and Name columns. You need to examine your file with an hex editor, or a text editor that shows non printable chars. (also the debugger could help)

Comment: yeah i know that.. but i have to work with the same file.. any solution plz... there is two tabs between those.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in the header line between the `Name` and `gMNo` columns there is single white space between two tab chars.  And this space is considered a column name (You could see it in the dataGrid with the name `Column1`).

You could add this blank to the list of separator chars used by the split method.
(Fortunately it seems that you don't have columns names that contains embedded spaces.

```
   foreach (var columnName in lines.FirstOrDefault()
        .Split(new[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName);
    }
```

Then the problem seems to be present also in the lines with the values, but this time the invalid sequence seems to be between the columns `EnNo` and `Name`. Again, adding the space between the separators chars used by Split should resolve the problem

```
foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(1))
{
    var cellArray = cellValues
        .Split(new[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
}
```

Of course you need to be sure that the extraneous chars are spaces. An Hex Editor, a Text Editor that shows non printable chars or the debugger itself could help to find the exact char to add to the split separator list

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer here:

I just replaced

```
foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(
{
    var cellArray = cellValues
        .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
}
```

with

```
foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(1))
{
    var cellArray = cellValues
        .Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions);
    //if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
}
```